# Post method in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, http, angular

I am trying to use post form data to database, I am trying to add my data to database, I think I missed something.
           I am new to angular trying to learn and I dont know how to use post method and what should I put into json stringify. Please can someone help.
This is my template

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [ngFormModel]="form" #f="ngForm">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="formHeading">Facebook</div>
        <input type="text" id="fb" ngControl="fb">
          <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="f.form.controls.fb.touched &&       !f.form.controls.fb.valid">Facebook address is required</div>
      </div>


     <div class="form-row">
        <div class="formHeading">Google</div>
        <input type="text" id="gl" ngControl="gl">
        <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="f.form.controls.gl.touched && !f.form.controls.gl.valid">Google address is required</div>
    </div>


     <div class="form-row">
        <div class="formHeading">Twitter</div>
        <input type="text" id="twt" >

    </div>


     <div class="form-row">
        <div class="formHeading">LinkedIn</div>
        <input type="text" id="li" >

    </div>



    <div class="form-row">
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!f.form.valid">Save</button>
    </div>
```

My Component

```
       import {Component} from '@angular/core';

        import {FormBuilder, Validators, ControlGroup, FORM_DIRECTIVES}            from '@angular/common';
          import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
          import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
          import {Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

          @Component({
    selector: 'social-form',
    directives:[FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    templateUrl: './components/social/social.html',
    providers: [FormBuilder]
     })
        export class Social {
             http;
              form;

         constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {

             this.form = fb.group({
             "fb": ['', Validators.required],
             "gl": ['',Validators.required],


             });
          }

            onSubmit() {


        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        this.http.post('http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/poc-post/', JSON.stringify({?????????????}),{headers:headers})
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())

    }
}


I am trying to add my data to database,i think i missed something.
       I am new to angular trying to learn and i dont know how to use post method and what should i put into json stringify.Please can someone help.
```

Comment: You should stringify your model class, but I don't see one. So you could just pass an object instead of `JSON.stringify({?????????????}),` for example `{"twt":  $('#twt').value() }`

Comment: @AngJobs You gave terrible example with jQuery.

Comment: Sure, bind a class property instead

Answer (score 0):

You can pass ngForm value to your onSubmit() method:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)">
```

Then:

```
onSubmit(form:any) {
  let body = JSON.stringify({ form });
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-type': 'application/json' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  this.http.post(url, body, options)
           .map((res: Response) => res.json())
           .subscribe();
}
```

Don't forget to `subscribe();` because the `http.post` does not send the request just yet! This observable is cold which means the request won't go out until something subscribes to the observable

Comment: Hi ,what should i write in subscribe?

Comment: i did thisss     var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        this.http.post('http://localhost/a2server/index.php/profile/addsocial', JSON.stringify({facebook:"dsd",google:"dssdj"}),{headers:headers})
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
             .subscribe((res:Person) => this.postResponse = res);
             
           
    }
}
class Person{
    facebook:string;
    google:string;
    twitter:string;
    linkedin:string;
}

Comment: should i need to add anything in my form

Comment: <div class="form-row">
        <div class="formHeading">Google</div>
        <input type="text" id="gl" ngControl="google">

Comment: Your subscribe is correct, are you giving any exception?

Comment: No Kayo,i am not thinking of it as of now